# classic for loop vs Arraylist forEach in concurrently filled list - Java 8

Tags: java, multithreading, arraylist, java-8, thread-safety

I'm using the Java 8 iterator over an array list. Suppose I have an ArrayList of futures, is there any problem/recommendation between using the classic for loop vs the arraylist foreach? (Besides not being able to throw an exception from within the lambda expression)

Suppose that the futureList is being filled concurrently, what would be the best approach? Is the last foreach example prone to any issues?

If I'm not wrong, this is the Arraylist foreach source code from jdk 1.8_131:

```
@Override
public void forEach(Consumer<? super E> action) {
    Objects.requireNonNull(action);
    final int expectedModCount = modCount;
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    final E[] elementData = (E[]) this.elementData;
    final int size = this.size;
    for (int i=0; modCount == expectedModCount && i < size; i++) {
        action.accept(elementData[i]);
    }
    if (modCount != expectedModCount) {
        throw new ConcurrentModificationException();
    }
}
```

These are the two alternatives on which I want advice:

```
public void waitForCompletion(List<Future<HttpResponse>> futureList) {
    futureList.forEach(future -> {
        try {
            future.get();
        } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
            LOG.error("Something went wrong: ", e);
        }
    });
}
```

vs

```
private void waitForCompletion(List<Future<HttpResponse>> futureList) {
    for(int i=0; i < futureList.size(); i++) {
        try {
            futureList.get(i).get();
        } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
            LOG.error("Something went wrong: ", e);
        }
    }
}
```

In which case it is not recommended to use?:

```
private void waitForCompletion(List<Future<HttpResponse>> futureList) {
    for(Future<HttpReponse> future:futureList) {
        try {
            future.get();
        } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
            LOG.error("Something went wrong: ", e);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Eh.  Use whatever reads best; there's not likely to be a significant difference relative to the cost of your operation.  There is not a strong recommendation here.  (You might also consider the for-each loop, rather than an indexed for loop, though: `for (Future<HttpResponse> future : futureList)`.)

Comment: There seem to be differences in terms of performance https://www.infoq.com/news/2015/12/BenchmarkingStreams and https://www.infoq.com/presentations/java8-stream-performance

Comment: If it were extremely performance critical, the classic for loop avoids most overhead and creates no temporary objects (iterator, lambda). But in any normal scenario I prefer the more compact forms-

Comment: Just use the one you like the most. performance differences in iteration are negligible in this context, where there are concurrent tasks, futures, etc (i.e. a lot of overhead)

Comment: Now you've changed your question, making most of the answers so far useless. Original question didn't mention that the list was to be filled concurrently. Btw, *why* do you need such thing?

Comment: @FedericoPeraltaSchaffner yes sorry, I missed that clarification..

Comment: But in general, when you have a list of Futures, you don't need the list to be synchronized in order to get the results

Comment: Having a list of futures which complete concurrently is *not* the same as filling the list concurrently. The list doesn’t change.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your case, you can just using `for-each` loop instead:

```
private void waitForCompletion(List<Future<HttpResponse>> futureList) {
    for(Future<HttpReponse> future:futureList) {
        try {
            future.get();
        } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
            LOG.error("Something went wrong: ", e);
        }
    }
}
```

*Note*: [ArrayList#get](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#get-int-) don't support **fail-fast** feature, so your second approach is different with your first one.

> fail-fast: if the list is structurally modified at any time after the iterator is created, in any way except through the iterator's own remove or add methods, the iterator will throw a ConcurrentModificationException. Thus, in the face of concurrent modification, the iterator fails quickly and cleanly, rather than risking arbitrary, non-deterministic behavior at an undetermined time in the future.

for example:

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
list.add(1);
Iterator<Integer> it = list.iterator();

it.next(); // return 1;

list.add(2);// the list is modified 
it.next();
// ^--- fail-fast throws a ConcurrentModificationException
```

### Edit

the `for-each` loop is equivalent to [ArrayList#forEach](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#forEach-java.util.function.Consumer-), they are both support **fail-fast** feature. the different between them is `for-each` loop can throws a checked `Exception` **directly**, for example:

```
private void waitForCompletion(List<Future<HttpResponse>> futureList)
                                                   throws Exception {
    for(Future<HttpReponse> future:futureList) {
         future.get();
    }
}
```

Another bit different is [Array#forEach](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#forEach-java.util.function.Consumer-) only create a lambda expression instance once. but `for-each` loop will create a new `Iterator` for each call, for example:

```
void forEachLoop(){
  //          v--- create a new Iterator when forEachLoop was called.
  for(T item:items);
}

void forEach(){
                // v--- create a single lambda instance.
  items.forEach(it->{});
}
```

Comment: I've updated the question with regarding your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Cost wise I believe they are almost identical--just depends what is going on behind the scenes and what you chose to write yourself. Readability-wise, it is usually nicer to use the for-each style loops due to the easy reference of individual objects in a list.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a synchronized list for your purpose:

```
List<Future<HttpResponse>> objList = 
      Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<Future<HttpResponse>>());
```

When performing concurrent thread operations, the access to each independent process must be thread-safe. You are building a thread-execution service, and you will not run the risk that two future-tasks update the list simultaneously, e.g. through their return objects.

*Alternative*

Note further that you could also configure a threadpool of 'Runnable' Java classes, as elements of your list. Here is an implementation that I have actual production experience with (based on `ConcurrentHashMap`):

```
Map<ReturnData, Map<String, String>> returnMap = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
ExecutorCompletionService<Map<ReturnData, Map<String, String>>> exService = new ExecutorCompletionService<>(executorServiceGetReturnData);

List<Callable<Map<ReturnData, Map<String, String>>>> callMethods = new ArrayList<>(ReturnData.size());
```

Comment: No, you don't have to use a synchronized list. And if it were the case, you are not explaining why. Besides, this looks more like a comment than an answer, IMO.

Comment: See my extended reply

Comment: But OP is asking about forEach vs classic for loop... What does your answer have to do with that?

Comment: This interesting question is broader than only addressing how to loop through a List, as it concerns a List of  process-threads running in parallel. I removed a pitfall in this use-case, and extended it using a Map of 'Callables'.

Answer (score 0):

A few years ago I compiled a class containing a for each loop them decomplied it. Using jd-gui.

My loop

```
for (Object object: objectList) {
    // Stuff
}
```

Decomplied to

```
for (into i =0 ; i < objectList.lenght(); i ++) {
    Object object = objectList.get(i);
    // Stuff
}
```

So they are basically equivalents (or at least they were in java 5)